# How to implement batch backpropagation

Tags: c++, machine-learning, backpropagation

I have successfully implemented stochastic backpropagation and I am trying to increase its accuracy. I've noticed batched backpropagation seems to be more popular I wanted to try and see if that will improve the network's accuracy, however I can't seem to figure out how to implement it. By "batched backpropagation" I mean backpropagation where the weights and biases are only updated after the completion of a mini-batch or epoch instead of updating it after each input.

My understanding is that you sum up the changes that are needed to be made to each weight and bias and apply the change at the end of the batch of training examples. I basically changed nothing from my original stochastic backprop code except instead of applying the change directly to the weights and biases I apply the change to a buffer which is then used to update the weights and biases later. Or am I supposed to sum up the cost from each training example and then at the end of the batch run backpropagation? If this is the case then what do I use for the intermediate results (the output vectors of each layer) if the cost is a combination of the cost for a batch of inputs?

```
//Called after each calculation on a training example
void ML::NeuralNetwork::learnBatch(const Matrix & calc, const Matrix & real) const {
  ML::Matrix cost = 2 * (calc - real);
  for (int i = weights.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      //Each element in results is the column vector output for each layer
      //ElementMultiply() returns Hadamard Product
      ML::Matrix dCdB = cost.elementMultiply(ML::sigDerivative(weights[i] * results[i] + biases[i]));
      ML::Matrix dCdW = dCdB * results[i].transpose();
      cost = weights[i].transpose() * dCdB;

      sumWeights[i] += learningRate * dCdW; //Scalar multiplication
      sumBiases[i] += learningRate * dCdB;
      /* Original Code:
       * weights[i] -= learningRate * dCdW;
       * biases[i] -= learningRate * dCdB;
      */ 
  }

}
//Called at the end of a batch
void ML::NeuralNetwork::update() {

  for (int i = 0; i < weights.size(); ++i) {
      weights[i] -= sumWeights[i];
      biases[i] -= sumBiases[i];

      //Sets all elements in the matrix to 0
      sumWeights[i].zero();
      sumBiases[i].zero();

  }
}
```

Besides the addition of an `update()` function I really haven't changed much from my working stochastic backprop code. With my current batch backprop code the neural network never learns and consistently gets 0 correct outputs even after iterating over 200 batches. Is there something I'm not understanding?

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In batch back propagation, you sum the contribution of the backpropagation of each sample.

In other terms, the resulting gradient is thus the sum of the gradient of each sample.

Comment: Isn't that pretty much what I'm doing? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I'm answering this question: "I basically changed nothing from my original stochastic backprop code except instead of applying the change directly to the weights and biases I apply the change to a buffer which is then used to update the weights and biases later. Or am I supposed to sum up the cost from each training example and then at the end of the batch run backpropagation?". You sum the gradients.

Comment: The math behind is actually quite involved, but @MatthieuBrucher gave you the correct answer! If you want to read in-depth why it is like that, I wrote about it on https://biasandvariance.com/batched-backpropagation-connecting-math-and-code/.